# Validate user login info client side BEFORE sending it to api (php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to find out how I, in the best and easiest possbile way, can check whether the login info is correct, already in the client side before the user gets send to the login.php (API).

I was thinking about creating som methods in JS that looked at the validation through another api, maybe validate-login.php, and if this method returned "success" or something, then it would allow the API call to go through. But I do simply not know how I can do this?

I can create another validate-login.php file but I do not know how to use this for the check of both username and password BEFORE going to login.php, and how I tell it NOT to go to login.php if that API returns "error" or something.

Was thinking of something onkeyup() but that only applies for one field at a time I guess, and I need it to check the combo of two?

This is what I got so far:

```js
//Function that validates the login info all together does the combo of username and password exists?
  function validateLogin() {
    //Some frontend - client side - validation before the AJAX call can happen
    
    $.ajax({
      "method" : "POST",
      "url" : "../tinder/api/validate-login.php",
    }).done(function(data) {
      //If response = 0 - Validation went fine - User should be sent to api: login.php
      
      //If response = 1 - Wrong username and/or password - User should be prompted with the error on the current side

    }).fail(function() {

    });
  }
```

```css
<?php
//File that handles the login process of the user
  $sFileName = '../txt/users.txt';

  $sUsername = $_POST['username'];
  $sPassword = $_POST['password'];

  //If username and password field is set = NOT empty
  if(!empty($sUsername) && !empty($sPassword)) {
    
    //echo 'Okay a username and password has been filled out';   //Only for test
    
    $sajUsers = file_get_contents($sFileName);
    $ajUsers = json_decode($sajUsers);

    //Go through the users in the array to check
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ajUsers); $i++) {   

      //Check if username and password combo does exist in file
      if($ajUsers[$i]->username == $sUsername && $ajUsers[$i]->password == $sPassword) {
        //echo 'Yes username and password combo exists';      //Only for test
        
        //Check if user is verified - Meaning that they have already confirmed through email link
        if($ajUsers[$i]->verification == true) {
          //User has already activated the account through email link
          echo 'Account is ready to go';    //Only for test

          //Check if an image is already set
          if($ajUsers[$i]->imageSet == true) {
            //User has an uploaded image
            //TODO: Redirect to page where users will be shown randomly
            echo 'Image has been set';    //Only for test
          } else {
            //User must upload an image
            //TODO: Redirect to user-profile page, where user must upload an image
            echo 'Image must be uploaded in order to continue';    //Only for test  
          }

        } else {
          //User must activate account first
          //TODO: Redirect to start page with modal/popup telling them, that they need to activate account through mail
          echo 'You must activate account first';   //Only for test    
        }
      }

    }

    //Check if user has an image set for them - Otherwise redirect to profile-page
    //TODO

  } else {
      echo '{"status" : "error", "message" : "Username or password was not field out"}';
      header('refresh: 3; url=http://localhost:8888/tinder/');
      exit;
  }

?>
```

```html
<!-- Login Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="login-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="login-modal-label">Login</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <form id="frm-login" action="api/login.php" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="input-login-username">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="input-login-username" placeholder="Enter username" onkeyup="validate-login()">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input-login-password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="input-login-password" placeholder="Enter password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="remember-me-check">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember-me-check">Remember me</label>
                <div class="text-right">
                  <!-- TODO: align link with checkbox and label but just to the right -->
                  <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" class="mr-auto" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup-modal">Need an account?</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Define "validate" -- do you mean ensure that the strings meet some minimum criteria for length and format? Or do you mean actually check that the user has provided the correct password?

Comment: What is your intention here? What would be the point of a "check of both username and password BEFORE going to login.php"? Why would you ever need to check the credentials twice? What could `validate-login.php` do that `login.php` could not? Please stop trying to reinvent internet security. There are established ways of doing things, that were invented for a reason. Quite simply you do not have enough information to invent a better way or you would not be asking questions here.

Comment: I do not mean validate like min length.. I mean that the match actually exists! Match between password and username.. So that I do not redirect the user to login.php just to tell them, that it was a wrong match

Comment: gforce301

I just don't want to redirect them to another page if all this page is going to say, is that it was wrong.. I am quite new to web development, so definitely not trying to reinvent anything.. :)

Comment: If you have an AJAX target that validates the username and password, then you don't need a login page. Submit the AJAX request when the user clicks the login button. The AJAX endpoint should validate the info, and put the user information into a session on success. On the client side, if you get an error, use jquery to display it. If you don't get an error, then redirect to the my_account page. (Or whatever.) The my_account page (and all other pages) then need to look in the session to verify authentication.

Comment: Hi Alex,
Thanks alot. Only problem though is that this session thing and how to make the pages look into the session seems quite "out of my reach" at the moment. I do understand the concept, but needs to be used practically by my hands :P

Is there any tuts online that kinda do what I want to with login, validation, sessions and redirection :)? Or at least the session part in the validation-api?